# How to match efficiently against keys in a table in Lua?

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, pcre, lpeg

Available in my Lua 5.1 environment are obviously the default Lua pattern matching, but also a reasonably recent version of PCRE and LPEG. I don't honestly care which of these is used; as long as my problem is tackled in an efficient manner I'm happy. (My personal knowledge of LPEG especially is next to non-existent, but I hear it has some very good qualities.)

I have a table with certain string patterns as keys, the accompanying values are to be used once the keys matches... which means they aren't really important for this matter.

Suppose you have:

```
tbl = { ["aaa"] = 12, ["aab"] = 452, ["aba"] = -2 }
```

Now my goal is to find out which one of these matches first in a particular string like `"accaccaacaadacaabacdaaba"`.

In reality, the keys are more numerous and the match string is considerably lengthier. This means simply matching against all keys one by one and compare the column the match begins at is a very inefficient solution that is not viable for me.

Parts of the match strings can have considerable overlaps, too. From the theory, I know one state machine per key pattern would be ideal in this regard; just go through the motions on every pattern and the moment you have a complete match on one of them you are done.

But I would be crazy to go code something like that myself when there's so many pattern matching libraries in my environment. The only one I know is *technically* capable is PCRE; just append the keys like `"aaa|aab|aba"` and you'll get the first feasible match.

But there's also the problem. For one, I am unsure how intelligent it is when compiling such a match. (I think it first tries 'aaa', unwinds completely once it fails, then completely tries aab, but I haven't tested) which wouldn't be too efficient compared to matching it like `"a(a[ab]|ba)"` where similarities get resolved faster.

Additionally, I'd like to have the capacity to put in some flexibility ("a.ad" where the second character doesn't matter, or matches a number.. basic stuff like that). With a pattern like that in such an additive approach, I do not see a way to regain the original pattern that matched so I can use the value that goes with it.

(Worst case, I could just generate a lot of entries in the table to match every possible wildcard variation and do away with the pattern requirement, but I honestly don't want to.)

Which library is the right tool for the job, and to boot, how to best use said library to achieve above-stated goals without reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Just implement the Aho–Corasick algorithm by yourself.

Comment: There's an algorithm I didn't know. I'll have a look at it. That said, I find it surprising such popular libraries like PCRE don't have an implementation of that algorithm built in...

Answer (score 0):

A comment to your question mentioned Aho–Corasick algorithm.

If your environment has access to `os.execute` or `io.popen`, you can call `fgrep -o -f patterns filename`, where `patterns` is the name of a file that contains patterns separated with newlines, and filename is the name of your input. `-o` means that only matches will be output, one per line. You can replace `filename` with `-` so that `fgrep` reads from standard input: `echo "String to match" | fgrep -o -f patterns`.

`fgrep` implements Aho–Corasick algorithm.

However, remember that Aho–Corasick algorithm does not recognise metacharacters.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Alexander Mashin's answer said, Aho–Corasick algorithm is an efficient algorithm that will solve your problem. In Lua land, [cloudflare /
lua-aho-corasick](https://github.com/cloudflare/lua-aho-corasick) is an implementation for LuaJIT using FFI. There's also a pure lua implemetation [jgrahamc/aho-corasick-lua](https://github.com/jgrahamc/aho-corasick-lua) which might be slower.